# Configure Jenkins to generate fake dll

Tags: jenkins, configuration

We are trying to run all the vstest unit test cases as part of our CI.

I want to generate fake dll once after the actual dll is built in Jenkins.

is there any msbuild command to generate fakes dll out of C# dll that i can configure in Jenkins?

Right now we are actually generating the fake dll from visual studio 2013 and copying it to jenkins machine(predefined location).

This will be really helpful as i'm trying to get rid of manually generating the fake dll and copying it to jenkins machine every time there is a change in the actual dll.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on your question a little bit more?  I think that will help us narrow down a good answer for you.

In general, Jenkins can easily execute 2 compile steps in succession to generate both of your dlls before testing..  For example, in 2 different build steps, as a batch/shell/bash script, as downstream/pipeline jobs, or within a build scripting language like ant/maven/gradle.

Comment: We generate/build the fakes dll from VS 2013 manually using 'Add Fakes Assembly' and copy it to jenkins machine predefined location.Build machine will pick fakes dll from that location and run the unit test cases.

But the problem is every-time there is a change in the actual C# dll we need again regenerate the fakes dll manually and copy it to jenkins location.

I don't know how to configure the jenkins build to generate the respective fakes dll as soon as your actual dll is built.

is there any msbuild command to generate Microsoft fakes dll that i can configure in Jenkins?

Comment: According to [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10dc7b73-2b83-456e-897e-8544eabe88b6/msbuild-from-command-prompt-is-not-generating-the-fakeassemblies?forum=msbuild), msbuild can generate fakes dlls.  A quick google did come up with the steps needed to build them using [PowerShell](http://csharpening.net/?p=1381).  Perhaps you can create a powershell script you can invoke from Jenkins like this user did?